# how to make a cumulative layer plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a data similar to example below:

```
library(dplyr)
nycflights13::flights %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(day, month, year, sep = '-'), format = '%d-%m-%Y')) %>% 
  select(date, carrier, distance)
```

Now I need to build a plot with stacked sums of distance in each day, where subsequent layers would refer to different carriers. I mean something similar to

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, fill = cut)) + geom_area(stat = "bin")
```

but with `sum` as a `stat`.

I have tried with

```
nycflights13::flights %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(day, month, year, sep = '-'), format = '%d-%m-%Y')) %>% 
  select(date, carrier, distance) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_area(aes(date, distance, fill = carrier, group = carrier), stat = 'sum')
```

but it didn't do a trick, resulting in

> `Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`

It's pretty easy with `geom_bar`, but any ideas how to make a stacked `geom_area` plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
nycflights13::flights %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(day, month, year, sep = '-'), 
                        format = '%d-%m-%Y')) %>% 
  select(date, carrier, distance) %>% 
  group_by(date, carrier) %>% 
  summarise(distance = sum(distance)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_area(aes(date, distance, fill = carrier, 
                group = carrier), stat = 'identity')
```

should do the trick.
[image]

Comment: That's nice. I would from my personal experience avoid direct piping into the ggplot call. Assign your changed data frame to a new object. This makes it easier later to use several data frames for several plots, which you will most certainly have.